# Convert Base64 into byte and writes the specified byte array to the file and save it into Server MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postman

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SavePhoto(string base64)
{
    string file = "test.jpg";
    string Imgpath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Img/"), Path.GetFileName(file));
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Imgpath, Convert.FromBase64String(base64));

    return Json(new { status= true},JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

I make a request from Postman and send a Base64 string to the calling Action it's return **"true"** but no Image has been saved to the given path name **"Imgpath"**. If there is no issue with my code then why Image is not saving in the given path name **"Imgpath"**

Comment: anybody help me please....

Comment: is the file `~/Img/test.jpg` created? or not even this?

Comment: "Img" folder already created by me im my server but in "Img" folder the file with name "test.jpg" is not creating.

Comment: could you try out `Server.MapPath(@"~/Img/"),...`

Comment: Are you checking in the right directory? `Server.MapPath("~")` returns with a physical path to the root of the application. (ie in your application folder)

Comment: let me try this...

Comment: did you try to save it on the local hard drive? does this work?

Comment: yes i am 100% sure that I am checking in the right directory

Comment: how to save it to local hardrive...?

Comment: give it a path on your local machine, are you working with Linux or windows? or Mac OS?

Comment: @Mong Zhu actually it is saving into the project folder name "Img" in my local machine but in Visual Studio IDE the folder name "Img" show empty i refresh it again and agian but "Img" folder shows itself empty

Comment: so when you check through the normal file browser then the file `test.jpg` has been created in your project folder, but in the IDE it does not show up? If this is correct, then it seems not to be the same folder..

Comment: @Mong Zhu there is only Folder with name "Img" in my  Project in the local machine and int he IDE.

Comment: Try to use absolute path this time (eg `C:\Test\test.jpg`) instead, to verify if you are not looking elsewhere. If there is a file, then the method works. If not, then the problem is at the method itself. (Do you have sufficient permission?) Also verify if the above method is called (add a debug line - No 404 on client side?)

Comment: @Mong Zhuwhen Server.MapPath("~/Img/") is working localy but throws exception remotely. because the image is not saving into IDE. Please tell me how to Add image into IDE "Img" folder. I google it again and again but failed to find proper answer.